# Change keyboard input on ultra power saving

Tags: doze-mode

I own a gallaxy s5. And my battery really sucks so I often switch to ultra power saving mode.

I type a lot and I don't really like the default Samsung keyboard. I want to change the default to Gboard. Any help is greatly appreciated!